# Show uib-tooltip on mouseenter only if a condition is met?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm new to angular and struggling with this. I have several heading elements with a `truncate` class applied to them so that they will truncate if their content is longer than one line. I want to show a uib-tooltip with the full content of the heading on mouseenter, but I don't want the tooltip to show if the content has not been truncated. The condition is the easy part, using `scrollWidth` and `offsetWidth`. I have that part working.

I have tried dynamically applying the `uib-tooltip` attribute on `mouseenter` if the content is truncated, but this doesn't seem to work. I have also tried using the `tooltip-enable` attribute to no avail.

I am now wondering if I'm going about this all wrong, and if there is a much simpler way to achieve this.

Comment: it's `tooltip-enable`, not `uib-tooltip-enabled`

Comment: Thanks for catching that. `tooltip-enable` is what I was trying.

Comment: `tooltip-enable` seems to work fine, https://plnkr.co/edit/vMcSfnJA014mNfxR0Gyj?p=preview

Comment: @svarog, thanks for the example, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my case. If you have a moment, you can take a look at what I'm trying to accomplish here http://jsbin.com/fumema/3/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: `"but I'm not sure how to apply it to my case"`, you don't. my 2 cents on the matter is that you shouldn't define a directive for your case, because `uib-tooltip` and `tooltip-enable` already provide what you need

Comment: Perhaps the problem in my question is oversimplified and too far removed from the real context of 8a large app. In the app there are many elements of all kind (headings, spans, paragraphs, etc.) which truncate if their text is too long. When this happens, the user can view the original text in a tooltip by hovering that element. What I want to achieve is the above behaviour on _any_ element containing text simply by adding a `truncate` attribute directive. The directive handles adding the CSS class, and showing a tooltip when text gets too long. I have the condition, but not the tooltip.