# How can I add uib-tooltip from within an attribute directive?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Instead of adding `uib-tooltip="tooltip text"` to the element I want to add only a `tooltip` attribute.

In the tooltip directive I want to do something along the lines of "on mouseenter if a condition is met then show my full text content in uib-tooltip"

Comment: use tooltip-enable ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show uib-tooltip on mouseenter only if a condition is met?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297971/show-uib-tooltip-on-mouseenter-only-if-a-condition-is-met)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tooltip-enable`.

JS

```
.controller("ctrl", function($scope){

  $scope.isToolTipEnabled = false;

  $scope.toggleToolTip = function(){
    $scope.isToolTipEnabled = !$scope.isToolTipEnabled;
  }

});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div class="label label-info" class="btn btn-default"
          tooltip-enable="isToolTipEnabled" 
          uib-tooltip="This is a conditional tooltip">Conditional Tooltip here</div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleToolTip()" ng-class="{'btn-success': isToolTipEnabled, 'btn-danger': !isToolTipEnabled}">Tooltip is {{isToolTipEnabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}}</button>
</div>
```